# FTPS for transferring file from unix to mainframe

Tags: unix, mainframe, data-transfer, jcl, outbound

I am looking for JCL Script/Procedures in mainframe which can facilitate file transfer from Unix server to Mainframe.I am required to do **FTPS for the Outbound Jobs (pull the file from UNIX server to mainframe Host).**

Comment: what have this got to do with a database `stored procedure` ?

Comment: yes my bad ,need a Jcl sample script/pointers  that facilitates the transfer

Comment: Presumbaly you are not the first person in your organisation to require this so go talk to the network people or scheduling people or other people that do this.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a JCL, just do it a shell script. Here is a good site on using such commands:
https://blog.eduonix.com/shell-scripting/how-to-automate-ftp-transfers-in-linux-shell-scripting/

Once you have that working in the shell script in USS, you should be able to call the shell script from a JCL so you can execute it on a scheduled batch job if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Kenny's suggestion is fairly reasonable. IBM's documentation on how to write JCL for FTP(S)-related tasks is available in their "z/OS Communications Server: IP User's Guide and Commands" publication, IBM Publication No. SC27-3662. The current revision appears to be SC27-3662-30, but later revisions are possible. You can easily find this publication online, and make sure you don't skip the section beginning with the title "Submitting FTP requests in batch." Make sure you set the security options correctly (of course).

Please note that you're asking about FTPS, i.e. TLS encryption applied to either or both (preferably both) of the FTP channels (control and data). SFTP is another file transfer protocol based on SSH that z/OS also supports.

Another possible approach that you'll fairly often find available on z/OS installations is to use IBM MQ Advanced for z/OS's Managed File Transfer (MFT) feature to retrieve the file(s) using FTPS. As the name suggests, this'll be managed and have at least some error handling capabilities.

Yet another possible approach if you prefer HTTPS protocol is to use the z/OS Client Web Enablement Toolkit's HTTPS protocol enabler to fetch the file. That's a built-in, standard feature in all currently supported z/OS releases, and you can use it from a relatively simple REXX script for example. Details are available here (z/OS 2.3 variant of the documentation):

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.ieac100/ieac1-cwe-http.htm